# Problemas com JPA - Hibernate nao persiste TODO o objeto

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Bom dia galera!

Tenho as seguintes entidades:

```java
package br.com.sistema.entidade;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_Carrinho")
@IdClass(CarrinhoDeComprasID.class)
public class CarrinhoDeCompras {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_produto")
    private Produto produto;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_venda")
    private Venda venda;

    private Integer quantidade;

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public Venda getVenda() {
        return venda;
    }

    public void setVenda(Venda venda) {
        this.venda = venda;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((produto == null) ? 0 : produto.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((quantidade == null) ? 0 : quantidade.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((venda == null) ? 0 : venda.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CarrinhoDeCompras other = (CarrinhoDeCompras) obj;
        if (produto == null) {
            if (other.produto != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!produto.equals(other.produto))
            return false;
        if (quantidade == null) {
            if (other.quantidade != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!quantidade.equals(other.quantidade))
            return false;
        if (venda == null) {
            if (other.venda != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!venda.equals(other.venda))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
package br.com.sistema.entidade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_PRODUTO")
public class Produto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String descricao;

    @Column(name="data_cadastro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataCadastro;

    private Double valor;

    @Column(name="quantidade_vendida")
    private Integer quantidadeVendida = 0;

    //Construtores  
    public Produto() {  
    }

    public Produto(String descricao, Date dataCadastro,
            Double valor) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    // Get's e Set's 
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Date getDataCadastro() {
        return dataCadastro;
    }

    public void setDataCadastro(Date dataCadastro) {
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
    }

    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidadeVendida() {
        return quantidadeVendida;
    }

    public void setQuantidadeVendida(Integer quantidadeVendida) {
        this.quantidadeVendida = quantidadeVendida;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((dataCadastro == null) ? 0 : dataCadastro.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((descricao == null) ? 0 : descricao.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((quantidadeVendida == null) ? 0 : quantidadeVendida
                        .hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((valor == null) ? 0 : valor.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Produto other = (Produto) obj;
        if (dataCadastro == null) {
            if (other.dataCadastro != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dataCadastro.equals(other.dataCadastro))
            return false;
        if (descricao == null) {
            if (other.descricao != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!descricao.equals(other.descricao))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (quantidadeVendida == null) {
            if (other.quantidadeVendida != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!quantidadeVendida.equals(other.quantidadeVendida))
            return false;
        if (valor == null) {
            if (other.valor != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!valor.equals(other.valor))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
package br.com.sistema.entidade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;


@Entity
@Table(name="TB_VENDA")
public class Venda implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="venda_id")
    private Integer vendaId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_cliente", nullable=false) // No banco esse campo vai se chamar id_cliente | Não pode ser nulo
    private Cliente cliente;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="venda")
    private List<CarrinhoDeCompras> produto;

    @Column(name="data_venda")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataVenda;

    private Double valorTotal;

    @Column(name="flag_venda_ativa")
    private Integer flagVendaAtiva;

    //Construtor
    public Venda(){

    }

    public Venda(List<CarrinhoDeCompras> p, Cliente c){
        this.produto = p;
        this.cliente = c;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public List<CarrinhoDeCompras> getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(List<CarrinhoDeCompras> produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public Date getDataVenda() {
        return dataVenda;
    }

    public void setDataVenda(Date dataVenda) {
        this.dataVenda = dataVenda;
    }

    public Integer getVendaId() {
        return vendaId;
    }

    public void setVendaId(Integer vendaId) {
        this.vendaId = vendaId;
    }

    public Double getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(Double valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    public Integer getFlagVendaAtiva() {
        return flagVendaAtiva;
    }

    public void setFlagVendaAtiva(Integer flagVendaAtiva) {
        this.flagVendaAtiva = flagVendaAtiva;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((cliente == null) ? 0 : cliente.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((dataVenda == null) ? 0 : dataVenda.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((flagVendaAtiva == null) ? 0 : flagVendaAtiva.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((produto == null) ? 0 : produto.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((valorTotal == null) ? 0 : valorTotal.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((vendaId == null) ? 0 : vendaId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Venda other = (Venda) obj;
        if (cliente == null) {
            if (other.cliente != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cliente.equals(other.cliente))
            return false;
        if (dataVenda == null) {
            if (other.dataVenda != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dataVenda.equals(other.dataVenda))
            return false;
        if (flagVendaAtiva == null) {
            if (other.flagVendaAtiva != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!flagVendaAtiva.equals(other.flagVendaAtiva))
            return false;
        if (produto == null) {
            if (other.produto != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!produto.equals(other.produto))
            return false;
        if (valorTotal == null) {
            if (other.valorTotal != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!valorTotal.equals(other.valorTotal))
            return false;
        if (vendaId == null) {
            if (other.vendaId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!vendaId.equals(other.vendaId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Qual e a bronca que está acontecendo...
Quando eu executo o método **salvar**:

```java
    @Override
    public void salvar(Object obj){
        try {
            abrirTransacao();
            this.em.persist(obj);
            fecharECommitarTransacao();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            rollback();
        }
    }
```

```java
package br.com.sistema.entidade;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class CarrinhoDeComprasID implements Serializable{

    private int produto;
    private int venda;

    public int getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(int produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public int getVenda() {
        return venda;
    }

    public void setVenda(int venda) {
        this.venda = venda;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + produto;
        result = prime * result + venda;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CarrinhoDeComprasID other = (CarrinhoDeComprasID) obj;
        if (produto != other.produto)
            return false;
        if (venda != other.venda)
            return false;
        return true;
    }       
}
```

[image: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/nMCM9TYRTT66EKqRaF7X]
Ele só salva o objeto venda sem as referências, ou seja, salva na tabela de Vendas mas a de Carrinho fica vazia.
Alguém tem alguma solução ou ideia para esse problema?
Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Parceiro, caso queira algo para facilitar em seus projetos utilizando Hibernate, eis um link que poderá te ajudar: https://github.com/KaynanCoelho/generic-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abra sua entidade `Venda` e onde você mapeou o `Carrinho`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="venda")
private List<CarrinhoDeCompras> produto;
```

Adicione o Cascade:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="venda", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<CarrinhoDeCompras> produto;
```

Depois tente salvar novamente. Da uma lida sobre os `Cascades` que vai te ajudar bastante. Aqui tem um **[excelente artigo](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Você já debugou o seu código e verificou se o objeto que chega no método salvar está populado com os atributos da List. Sugiro você forçar a passagem de parametro antes de chamar o método salvar

Exemplo em sua controller voce pode fazer assim

```
public class MinhaController {
    private class Venda venda;
    private class Service service;
    private List<CarrinhoDeProdutos> produtosList;

    public void salvar() {
        venda.setProdutos(produtosList);
        service.salvar(venda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim sim, já conferir.
Esta quase dessa forma, mas posso te garantir que o objeto esta TODO populado.